# generating of sheets per class for Parent-Teacher Meetings

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vbscript

I have to create an Excel spreadsheet for Parent-Teacher Meetings.
In the master sheet I will put two columns. The first column is for the name of the teacher, the second column is for the name of the classroom where the meeting will take place.

[image: Master sheet]

Each classroom can accommodate several teachers.
I would like to automatically create a new sheet for each classroom, to hang in each classroom, like to this:

[image: Class room sheet example]

The sheet then must have a column for each teacher present in that classroom.
The sheet name must also match the name of the classroom.

Comment: what part of it are you stuck on ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354078/automatically-creating-worksheets-based-on-a-list-in-excel) did what you need?

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share sample data with us (contents of Master Sheet & Class room sheet),, will help us to fix it!

Comment: @rajesh-s Thanks for your advice. Now I do this.

Comment: @p-phidot Not really what I was looking for

Comment: @peterh I don't know how to start

Comment: Since you have unique list of teachers then better you use the TRASPOSE command, solves the issue!!